# Unwanted Conversion in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm facing this strange error while using Spring Data JPA. This my Entity class...

```
// imports

@Entity
public class Activity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String activity;

    public Activity() {}

    public Activity(String activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

And the Controller class is...

```
// imports

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/students/activity")
public class ActivityController {
    @Autowired
    private ActivityService activityService;
    
    @GetMapping("/new-activity") 
    public String displayForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("newActivity", new Activity());
        return "students/activity-form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/save-activity")
    public String saveActivity(Activity activity){

        activityService.save(activity);
        return "redirect:/students/activity/new-activity";
    }

}
```

I'm using thymeleaf engine for view. This is my activity-form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head><title>Activity Form</title></head>
    <body>
        <form action="/students/activity/save-activity" th:object="${newActivity}" method="POST" >
            <label>Activity:</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{activity}">
            <button type="submit">Add activity</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everything seems to be fine for me, But when I submit the activity, It shows Bad Request , 400 Error in the browser and inside the console it displays this error

```
Resolved [org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'info.javacafe.studentforumapp.entities.Activity'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'activity 1'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "activity1"]
```

I think spring trying to convert my activity from String to Integer, But I don't know why this is happening. Can anyone help me and explain why this is happening?

Comment: The controller is expecting a json representation of your Activity class.. you are passing it a plain text string

Comment: yes @blurfus you're right, but in my entity class the field is declared with String only,  I don't know why it's trying to convert it into Integer.

Comment: share the request that you are trying and throwing exception

Comment: I'm requesting from my browser...

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: `Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'info.javacafe.studentforumapp.entities.Activity'`... This means the UI passed a String `"activity1"` instead of a JSON representation of the defined input (Activity) `{ "activity": "activity1" }`

Answer (score 1):

I think spring is trying to convert your `activity` text field into  `activity` parameter in your controller class.

Try changing that name to something else like below.

```
 @PostMapping("/save-activity")
public String saveActivity(Activity activityObject){
 //Notice that activity parameter is become activityObject
```

Pls try and let me know, I cant simulate this in my PC now.

Answer (score 0):

Update your controller method to

```
@PostMapping("/save-activity")
public String saveActivity(@ModelAttribute("newActivity") Activity activity){
    activityService.save(activity);
    return "redirect:/students/activity/new-activity";
}
```

I think the missing model attribute will get the form value mapped correctly.

Comment: Are you sure @RequestBody is not what he is looking for?

Comment: @DragosIonut according to this tutorial, nope: https://riptutorial.com/thymeleaf/example/29269/form-submission

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if `setActivity` has `Integer` parameter. Make sure it looks like this:

```
public void setActivity(String activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}
```